# Making VNC work on Ubuntu 12.10 LTS(Quantal Quetzal)

Tags: vnc, ubuntu-12.10

I have been trying to muck around with `xstartup`(in ~/`.vnc`) to try and get VNC to work like it usually does(i.e. mirror my desktop). Unfortunately, with my current xstartup('borrowed' from the pages linked below) I don't get any of the menus, launcher et al.

Apparently this has been a problem for others as well: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077657) and [here](http://kb.realvnc.com/questions/235/VNC+Server+in+Virtual+Mode+does+not+work+out-of-the-box+under+Ubuntu+12.10).

None of the 'solutions' on either of those links work for me and I was wondering if anyone had any working solutions at this time. Would switching from Ubuntu Unity to Gnome help?([1](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html), [2](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html)) Any suggestions, tips or work arounds are most welcome.

TIA.